# Python string replace containing "\"

Tags: python, string, replace

I would like to convert a string `temp.filename.txt` to `temp\.filename\.txt` using python

Tried string replace method but the output is not as expected

```
filename = "temp.filename.txt"
filename.replace(".", "\.")
output: 'temp\\.filename\\.txt'
```

Comment: I don't think `replace` modifies the string you call it on.  Did you mean `filename=filename.replace(".", "\.")`?

Comment: In a string parameter "\\." means "\.", "'\\\." means "\\."so on and so forth. You don't need to worry that your output is a wrong direction.

Comment: The only reason this works in the first place is because `\.` isn't recognized as a special escape sequence.  You should *always* double up \\ when using it in a string: `filename.replace(".", "\\.")`.

Comment: or use `r""` strings, but even these can trick you, e.g. if your string finishes with a  \, you'll still need to double up that last \...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\` is a special character, which is *represented* as `\\`, this doesn't mean your string actually contains 2 `\` characters.

(as suggested by @saipy, if you *print* your string, only single `\` should show up...)

Answer (score 0):

```
filename = "temp.filename.txt"
result=filename.replace(".", "\.")
print(result)
```

[I stored a result in variable(result) its working fine check this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/klc8N.png)

Comment: @Julien, can you click on the link for image

Comment: @Julien answer is correct. It's just how you see the string. Actually I was doing the right thing.